# django - can't assign a foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

For unknown reasons, I cannot assign a foreign key instance of `Item_rarity` table into `Detailed_item` table. Django throws an error:

**Cannot assign "u'Basic'": "Detailed_item.rarity" must be a "Item_rarity" instance.**

... But in `Item_rarity` dictionary "Basic" record exists - I can choose it from admin panel and create `Detailed_item` record manually.

I have defined models:

```
class Detailed_item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.IntegerField()
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    rarity = models.ForeignKey('Item_rarity')
    general_type = models.ForeignKey('Item_type')
    detailed_type = models.ForeignKey('Item_detailed_type')

class Item_rarity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)

class Item_type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)

class Item_detailed_type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

In views, I try to populate it in this manner (inserting multiple items):

```
...
   items = get_all_items()  #get dict of items
        for element in items:
            tmp_det_type = ''
            for key, val in element.iteritems():
            #get 'detailed type' from inner dict
                if key == "type":
                    tmp_det_type = val

            item = Detailed_item(
                item_id=element['id'],
                name=element['name'],
                level=element['level'],
                icon=element['icon'],
                rarity=element['rarity'],  #error
                general_type=element['type'],
                detailed_type=tmp_det_type,
                )

            item.save()

...
```

I even tried to hard code "Basic" string, but it doesn't work either.

*** Solved ***
Next two entries, that is `Item_type` and `Item_detailed_type` were also invalid. 
Correct code:

```
from app.models import Detailed_item, Item_rarity, Item_type, Item_detailed_type
...
   items = get_all_items()  #get dict of items
        for element in items:
            tmp_det_type = ''
            for key, val in element.iteritems():
            #get 'detailed type' from inner dict
                if key == "type":
                    tmp_det_type = val

                #create objects with string values
                obj_rarity = Item_rarity(name=element['rarity'])
                obj_item_type = Item_type(name=element['type'])
                obj_item_detailed_type = Item_detailed_type(name=tmp_det_type)

                item = Detailed_item(
                    item_id=element['id'],
                    name=element['name'],
                    level=element['level'],
                    icon=element['icon'],
                    rarity=obj_rarity,
                    general_type=obj_item_type,
                    detailed_type=obj_item_detailed_type,
                    )


            item.save()

...
```

Comment: It is expecting an object instance, What is the value of `element['rarity'] ` ?

Comment: It is a string "Basic", and can be printed without problems on stdio.

Comment: Ah, then the model expects an instance of rarity with the value `Basic`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Item_rarity` instance should be passed while storing `Detailed_item` object since Item_rarity is a foreign key related object in Detailed_item.

Its that you might have passed the `Basic` string instead of the `<Basic Object>` itself.

While creating an object in django using its ORM, any foreign_key related object should be provided with the instance itself instead of the id(pk) of the object, where as while fetching the data from the database you can use either of instance or the id(pk) of the instance.

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    model_field = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey('ParentModel')

parent_model = ParentModel.objects.create(model_field='some_data')

my_model = MyModel.objects.create(some_field=parent_model)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note here that the parent_model object itself is passed instead of the id

While fetching the data back,

```
parent_model = ParentModel.objects.get(model_field='some_data')

my_model = MyModel.objects.get(some_field=parent_model)

or

my_model = MyModel.objects.get(some_field=parent_model.id)
```

Both would work in case of data fetch.

Comment: It is possible to write it in shorter form, for example: my_model = parentModel(model_field='some data')

Comment: But whats the difference between both?

Comment: Version with .objects.create(...) creates an object and immediately inserts it into database, while the shorter version requires saving it with parentModel.save(). Trying Item_rarity.objects.create(...) inside a loop gave me an integrity error (trying to duplicate PK).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to provide the related object on creation if you change the kwarg in to `rarity_name`:

```
item = Detailed_item(
            item_id=element['id'],
            name=element['name'],
            level=element['level'],
            icon=element['icon'],
            rarity_name=element['rarity'],  # no error
            general_type=element['type'],
            detailed_type=tmp_det_type,
            )
```

I have only tested this with the regular `id` field (the auto pk) but it
should work with your primary key just fine.

E.g.

```
class SimpleModel(Model):
    value = TextField(blank=True)

class ComplexModel(Model):
    simple = ForeingKey(SimpleModel)
    title = TextField(unique=True)

ComplexModel.objects.create(title='test', simple_id=1)
```